# Tuple of types to tuple of instances

Tags: typescript, generics, tuples, typescript-generics, mapped-types

Consider the following Typescript:

```
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T

class Foo { }
class Bar { }

function magic(...types: Constructor[]) {
  // return tuple of instances in order
}

const [ foo, bar ] = magic([Foo, Bar])
```

What does an implementation of `magic()` look like such that it returns a `[Foo, Bar]` rather than a `(Foo | Bar)[]`?

How can it be made to support any number of constructors in any order?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fiddle the code until it worked:

```
class Foo { }
class Bar { }

type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T

type Constructors<T extends Constructor[]> = readonly [...T]

type Instances<T extends Constructor[], K extends Constructors<T>> = { 
    [I in keyof K]: K[I] extends Constructor<infer U> ? U : never 
}

function magic<T extends Constructor[], K extends Constructors<T>> (ctors: K): Instances<T, K> {
    return ctors.map(c => new c()) as any;
}

const [foo, bar, foo2, bar2] = magic([Foo, Bar, Foo, Bar])
```

`magic([Foo, Bar, Foo, Bar])` correctly returns a mapped tuple of type `[Foo, Bar, Foo, Bar]` instead of `(Foo | Bar)[]`.